# Parse Query on Nested Keys with Spaces

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

We need to perform analytics on custom objects stored within Parse.Object's. These objects have keys with spaces. Normally I would just use dot notation: `query.equalTo("metaData.custom_key", "custom value");` However, dot notation is not working in a case with spaces, as it would with a native MongoDB query.

Bad Queries with syntax error:

1. With spaces: `parseQuery.equalTo("metaData.key with spaces", "some value")`
2. With escape: `parseQuery.equalTo("metaData.key\ with\ spaces", "some value")`
3. With replace: `parseQuery.equalTo("metaData.key_with_spaces", "some value")`
4. With replace: `parseQuery.equalTo("metaData["key with spaces"]", "some value")`
5. With replace: `parseQuery.equalTo("metaData.'key with spaces'", "some value")`

These all result in errors like:

```
ParseError {
  code: 105,
  message: 'Invalid key name: metaData.\'key with spaces\'' }
```

E.g. ParseClass.metaData:

```
{ 
  "key with spaces":"some value",
  "key 2": "value 2"
}
```

These solutions are ***not*** preferable:
 1. Changing the metaData schema so there are no spaces in keys, because we have millions of objects in production using this format and production write scripts are risky.
 2. Using mongoose or native MongoDB queries, because Parse.Pointer's are stored in MongoDB as strings but we need relations.
3. Post-processing the metaData after a full query (inefficient; last resort).

The final result we need is to count the values for each unique key in the metaData object.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ParseQuery but you could try `("metaData['key with spaces']", ...)` or something like `("metaData.'key with spaces'")` .. is `metaData` an object, or does it have to be passed by string? could even try `(metaData["key with spaces"], ...)` if it's an object..?

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to mention I tried those too and they didn't work either. Adding to the post now.

Comment: Where does `metaData` come from? Is it an object or does it have to be passed via string?

Comment: It's a custom object to store users' data. It's saved using the Parse SDK.

Comment: I think saving all data again to parse with space-to-underscore-replacement of those keys is the only way to ensure a proper risk/reward-ratio. Trying to bypass Parse's no-space-in-keys-convention for Queries seems to cause more problems than it solves. Patching the mongo-adapter could be a good second option (please submit the to parse-server as well)

Comment: @coderofsalvation Thanks for the comment. We will consider patching the mongo-adapter, but I figured out a temporary work-around to get the data we need. Post-processing should do the trick for now.